# facebook special like button implement

Tags: php, css, facebook

I am tring to creat a facebook application here using TAP based on PHP.

However, I would like to make something like this.

http://www.facebook.com/BMWKorea?sk=app_187497311277576

If you see this e-commerce, there is a facebook like button in a image.

I think it has something to do with FBML, I do not exactly know how they did it.

Comment: Your link goes to homepage of page, not any app or tab. Updated link AND add screenshot. Having just a link means both question and answer will be useless if changed and/or solved.

Answer (score 0):

That is actually just an image designed with a facebook like button inside of it. If you right click it and open the image in a new window, you will see what I mean.

http://platform.ak.fbcdn.net/www/app_full_proxy.php?app=187497311277576&v=1&size=o&cksum=cfd2de05fa132a8f359bd59d187d5240&src=http%3A%2F%2Fm.magtoo.com%2Fimg%2Fbmw%2Fdiy%2Fimg_video_v2.jpg%3Fv3

Comment: i don't know... how to like button inside of it..
plz .. help.. t.t